# Configurable Topic name with Rebus

Tags: rebus

Topic needs to configrable via config file.

Below is the code. I wonder if this is the best solution or any built-in support, or better solution?

```
public class TopicNameConvention : ITopicNameConvention
{
    private readonly Config _config;

    public TopicNameConvention(Config config)
    {
        _config= config;
    }
    public string GetTopic(Type eventType)
    {
        switch (eventType.Name)
        {
            case nameof(Order):
                return _config.Topic.Name;

             //... more
        }
        throw new Exception("Topic name not exist");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intention is to manually be able to configure the topic name for each of your event types, then please go for it.

My own personal opinions is that this seems pretty rigid, and I would fear that you would have to update too many things at the same time, whenever you introduce a new event type.

Why not just go with

```cs
public string GetTopic(Type eventType) => eventType.Name;
```

which can handle all .NET types in the world (just be sure that you do not have two event types with the same name in two different namespaces).

Comment: The reason we need is that it provides flexibility, especially in dev. For example, image an Azure Service Bus is hosted called Order on development environment, However, a developer don't want to use the existing ASB because it is used by test team etc, he has to change the name of the ASB in the code. It is even worse when a wrapper of Rebus is in a nuget package, which makes the development worse. On production, it is also easier to change it having the configurable feature.